# How do I remove community wiki from one of my answers

Tags: support

I don't know how one of my answers got designated community wiki?  I must of hit something by accident but I don't understand how to take it off.

The question I answered was, "Is satisfaction absolute?"

Please let me know if I put this on community wiki, because if so it was an accident on my part; please tell me how to remove it.  If someone else put it on community wiki, then who was it and why?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was you, as you can see here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/45727/timeline

I don't think it's possible to remove it yourself, as sometimes answers are made wiki for reasons of moderation, I guess (have never seen that happen on this site though). So, the right way is what you did; ask on meta or flag the post.

I have removed the wiki from your answer now.

Comment: The mentioned link is for moderator only. Perhaps you could replace it with https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/45727/timeline for the public one? The public [revision history](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/45727/revisions) also shown when the OP converted it to a CW too.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks, I didn't know there were separate timelines.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this for me.  I suspected it was my own clumsiness.